# JAudioTagger Android tags update don't show on library refresh

Tags: android, android-mediaplayer, id3

I am using the jAudioTagger library to edit metadata of songs from my music player. The function to edit the tags is:

```
 save = (Button) findViewById(R.id.save);
    save.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View view) {

            File src = new File(filepath);

            songName=song.getText().toString();
            artistName=artist.getText().toString();
            albumName=album.getText().toString();



            try{
                TagOptionSingleton.getInstance().setAndroid(true);
                AudioFile f = AudioFileIO.read(src);
                f.setTag(new ID3v23Tag());
                Tag tag=f.getTag();
                tag.setField(FieldKey.TITLE,songName);
                tag.setField(FieldKey.ARTIST,artistName);
                tag.setField(FieldKey.ALBUM,albumName);

                f.commit();
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),"Done",Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }catch (Exception e){
                e.printStackTrace();
            }

        }
    });
```

However, after updating the tags, the change is not reflected anywhere. Even after refreshing my music library, the changes are not shown. How do I update the MediaStore to reflect the changes I've made to the tags so that all music players have access to the edited tags?

Comment: Instead of doing f.setTag(new ID3v23Tag());Tag tag=f.getTag(); just do Tag tag =  getTagOrCreateAndSetDefault() that way you dont lose existing metadata

Answer (score 1):

Instead of `audioFile.commit();` use `AudioFileIO.write(audioFile);`
If it doesn't work, use this method to scan your media

```
private void scanMedia(String path) {
    File file = new File(path);
    Uri uri = Uri.fromFile(file);
    Intent scanFileIntent = new Intent(
            Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_SCANNER_SCAN_FILE, uri);
    getContext().sendBroadcast(scanFileIntent);
}
```

Comment: It doesnt make any difference whether you use audioFile.commit() or AudioFileIO.write(audioFile)

Comment: where and when to use scanMedia?

Comment: @DeepSan just after the f.commit(), you can use the method scanMedia(filePath)

Comment: @Ibro, i have update song detail using Jaudiotagger, and when i get song detail using MediaStore.Audio.Media.EXTERNAL_CONTENT_URI, both are providing different detail. what can be the issue..